# Apache PDF digital signatures

Tags: javascript, apache, pdf, webforms

I have a website with a directory listing of all the pdf files which I have uploaded via ftp. By clicking any of the file names, the pdf document will show up in your web browser. Is it possible for outside parties to digitally signed the document in the web browser and save it back into the server with a appended "signed" on the file name.

My main problem is:

1. saving the signed document back into the server via the web browser
2. change the file name when the document is saved

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your permissions but if the user downloads it via http (you have directory listing enabled on your website) they should not be able to save it back to the site unless you allow it to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading the [PHP upload tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

You might consider WebDAV, but I would not recommend it.